# SFTP Public Key Authentication works for one user and no others

Tags: linux, sftp, key-authentication

I have one user who is able to able to login via SFTP using a public key, but can not setup any others to work the same way. I've searched for other similar questions and the solution has usually been related to ownership or permissions, but I've gone over this configuration dozens of times and everything lines up properly.

The desired result is to have a client that uses a single key pair to connect to the server using multiple accounts. With the current configuration, the contents of the authorized_keys files are identical for both users, and I am certain the the private key on the client side absolutely matches the public keys installed on the server.

The user that works:

```
# id ideal-dwh
uid=514(ideal-dwh) gid=514(ideal-dwh) groups=514(ideal-dwh),519(sftp-users)

# ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      sftp-users  4096 Jul 12 21:08 .
drwx-----x 6 root      root        4096 Jul 13 14:13 ..
drwx--x--- 2 root      sftp-users  4096 Jul 12 21:10 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 ideal-dwh sftp-users 36864 Jul 13 05:45 uploads

# cd .ssh
# ls -la
total 16
drwx--x--- 2 root sftp-users 4096 Jul 12 21:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root sftp-users 4096 Jul 12 21:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root sftp-users 1036 Jul 12 16:01 authorized_keys
```

And the user that doesn't work:

```
# id gapautoparts-dwh
uid=524(gapautoparts-dwh) gid=524(gapautoparts-dwh) groups=524(gapautoparts-dwh),519(sftp-users)

# ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 4 root             sftp-users  4096 Jul 13 14:13 .
drwx-----x 6 root             root        4096 Jul 13 14:13 ..
drwx--x--- 2 root             sftp-users  4096 Jul 13 14:13 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x 2 gapautoparts-dwh sftp-users 36864 Jul 13 14:13 uploads

# cd .ssh
# ls -la
total 16
drwx--x--- 2 root sftp-users 4096 Jul 13 14:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root sftp-users 4096 Jul 13 14:13 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root sftp-users 1036 Jul 13 14:13 authorized_keys
```

*sshd_config* contents

```
LogLevel VERBOSE
...
Match Group sftp-users
ChrootDirectory /data/%u
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /uploads
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

The *auth.log* file is blank and the secure log shows nothing related to the failed login attempts despite the log level being verbose in the config file.

The specific error I get when attempting to connect with the second user:

```
Status: Connecting to server...
Status: Using username "gapautoparts-dwh". 
Status: Server refused our key 
Status: Access denied 
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
Status: Disconnected from server
```

**What I have tried so far:**

*Changing permissions and ownership*

In researching the problem this seemed to be the most common solution. The recommended setup I usually see is to have the connecting user/group own the *.ssh* directory and it's contents, with 700 permissions on the *.ssh* directory and 600 permissions on the *authorized_keys* file. Changing this on the broken user that does not seem to make any difference. Furthermore, setting these owners/permissions on the working user actually breaks things.

I've tried just about every combination of ownership and permissions I can think of with no success. Changing the ownership and permissions of the currently working user to anything other than what I've already got breaks everything.

*Using a different key pair*

My desired result is to use a specific key pair to connect for both users, but in troubleshooting I have tried using different key pairs as well, updating the *authorized_keys* file as necessary.

This makes no difference for the broken user. For the working user I am able to connect using any key pairs I set up for the server and client.

*Starting from scratch with a new user*

The issue is not limited to the specific user I've shared in this post. I have created other users, following the same steps I used to create the working user and am unable to connect with any of them.

*Setting user-specific settings in sshd_config*

I have also tried adding user-specific rules to sshd_config in place of the group settings with no success. Adding the following makes no difference:

```
Match User gapautoparts-dwh
ChrootDirectory /data/gapautoparts-dwh
ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /uploads
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Have you checked the SSH logs on the server side?

Comment: For some reason my "auth.log" file is blank. The "secure" log does not seem to have anything relevant to the failed login attempts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: You have 2 users connecting with the same public key? Does this mean you're using the same key exchange for both users? As in, do you have the same private keys in their client-side `.ssh` folders with which to connect?

Comment: @Kahn yes, I've amended my post to clarify the private key on the client-side matches the public key installed for both users on the server.

Comment: How do the permissions/ownership on the client compare for the different users?

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the home directories were not properly set for new users.

Despite using the following command to create the user:

```
useradd -g sftp-users -d /data/gapautoparts-dwh/ gapautoparts-dwh
```

The entry in /etc/passwd was added as:

```
gapautoparts-dwh:x:524:524::/home/gapautoparts-dwh:/bin/bash
```

Why the -d flag isn't working is something else I'll have to look into, but this issue is resolved.

Comment: for -d flag misbehaving, try out appending -M option to your command